# Cocos2d running code after tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I can't figure out an if else code that says, if the screen is tapped, run //code (but it should only run once, acting on just the first tap).

I have a game that starts automatically once on the game scene (layer). I don't want the enemy AI to come until the screen is tapped, so I can show a tutorial .png before the AI come.

My code that I have automatically releases a monster ever 0.5 secs. I want the monsters to be released ever 0.5 seconds once the screen is tapped.

```
- (id)init {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    _curLevelIdx = 0;
    Level * level1 = [[[Level alloc] initWithLevelNum:1 secsPerSpawn:0.5 backgroundColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)] autorelease];
    _levels = [@[level1] retain];
}
return self;
}
```

This code is in the levelManager scene and it's just deciding the speed at which to spawn the monsters. And here is the code on the main scene that calls the schedule (it's inside a "-(id) init"):

```
[self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:[LevelManager sharedInstance].curLevel.secsPerSpawn];
```

And here is the code used that actually spawns the monster.

```
-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
    [self addMonster];
}
```

So I just need the code that adds the monsters to not act until the screen is tapped, and I have not been able to figure this out on my own.

Comment: can you send some more code ?  it quite not clear whats you problem.

Comment: is that enough info now?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct, you just want the user to tap and have it call your method to add the monster right? And for the monster to only be added once?

In your scene enable interactions in init or onEnter (example of onEnter)....

```
-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
}
```

Then override the touchesBegan method in your scene (assuming the monster is a property called monster)...

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.monster)
    {
        [self addMonster];
    }
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: I've edited my post and added addition code being used. Thanks for the help!